# Please select a 64 bit Debugger in the kit settings for this kit

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I downloaded qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.9.9.exe and when I tried to debug my application with QtCreator I got:

```
15:11:26: C:\...\myproject\build\bin\my_program.exe is a 64 bit executable which can not be debugged by a 32 bit Debugger.
Please select a 64 bit Debugger in the kit settings for this kit.
```

Where is the Qt installer for Windows 10 x64?

Comment: I think Qt creator clearly tells you what to do.

Answer (score 1):

[Select Debugger in Kit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkr2q.png)

Sometimes autodetection chooses the x86 instead of x64 on Windows.